# Xcode 13 - Hide git branch in Toolbar

Tags: xcode13

Welcome to Xcode 13, we can see/select current branch in the Toolbar.

[image: Git branch in Toolbar]

Don't get me wrong, it's great for some projects, but is there **any way to hide it?**
Did not find anything in a menu or preferences.
(I know I can completely disable git in preferences, I just want to 'hide' it from the Toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

The only way is going to Preferences -> Source control and **disable Enable Source control**

[Preferences Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iuUd.png)

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I'm trying to really 'hide' it, not disable git altogether.